# Can I re-process homemade applesauce canned in a boiling water canner that is too thick and pasty?

Tags: canning

The lids sealed well, but I think the apples were not juicy enough (maybe too tart) and the color of the applesauce after canning is slightly green. It's been less than 24 hrs. Maybe I didn't heat it hot enough before canning, since it was so thick.  I am thinking of starting over, adding some apple juice, and re-canning.  Will that work?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes you can re-process. Follow standard [processing procedure for applesauce](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_02/applesauce.html) once you get your applesauce to the taste and consistency you want. (Personally I like very thick applesauce.)

You said `Maybe I didn't heat it hot enough before canning, since it was so thick.` Did you bring it to boiling before putting it in the jars? If it was not hot at the time of packing you could possibly have a safety issue, depending on how long the jars were in the water bath. 
The applesauce being thick is only a canning/safety issue if there are large trapped air bubbles in the jar.

The color of the applesauce is not an indication of a problem. If you used tart apples they just didn't oxidize much. If you want to change the color you could add a bit of cinnamon. (it is possible it will darken up a little on it's own over time)